# Active high pass filter experiment result

Tags: active-filter, high-pass-filter, 741-opamp

[image]

[image]

The pictures above are the circuit model and plot. uA741 of Texas Instrument was used as an op-amp on the circuit.
1 Vrms was used as an input voltage so that the output can be the voltage gain.

The problem is that after 100 kHz the output voltage decrease even though it is HPF (High Pass Filter).
Could you tell me the reason or recommend some papers which can explain this phenomenon?

Comment: Gain-bandwidth limitation of your opamp. Don’t use uA741.

Comment: Yes - for small-signal analyses in the frequency domain, it is the small-signal bandwidth (GBW) which is responsible for the shown effect. (In reality, the slew rate limitations will govern for 741-like opamps).

Comment: Bak Gwang jin, please show/tell us which supply voltages you have selected.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to start is the data sheet.

The 741 is specified with a minimum slew rate of 0.5 V/us or 500 kV/s.

A sinusoid of amplitude \$Vrms\$ and frequency \$f\$ has a maximum slew rate at the zero crossing of \$2\pi f V\$. With 1 volt and 100 kHz, that's a slew rate of 628 kV/s. That's exactly where you'd expect to see the output level decreasing.

Some people will tell you to use something else than a 741. That doesn't solve your problem as all op-amps have a slew rate limit, that you'll hit at some frequency. So use an opamp that's fast enough for your application, or run your opamp within its limitations.

That said, the 741 is unusually slow, and there are a bunch of other good reasons why you should use a better amplifier.

Comment: I have got the impression that the questioner is - more or less - a beginner. Therefore, some comments/explanations: (1) I do not think that the slew rate is responsible for the shown results of an ac analysis. Slew rate limitations cannot be shown for ac small-signal analysis. Nevertheless, of course Neils comment is correct in general - however, its influence can be demonstrated in the time domain only (TRAN simulation). (2) When we discuss opamp properties, we often use the terms "slow" or "fast". You should know that these are synonyms for "small" resp. "large" small-signal bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are assuming op-amps are ideal. If op-amps were ideal, you only would need one type of op-amp and it would work perfectly with up to infinite power supplies and with infinite frequencies.

Actual op-amps are not ideal, and any electronics book that teaches op-amps usually considers what different non-idealities there are and how to take them into account.

In this case the op-amp can't work beyond 100kHz due to its limited bandwidth.

You don't need to read a any scientific papers, this is commonly covered in any electronics course book which teaches op-amps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the 741 has a GBW of 1MHz then, if slew-rate limiting didn't come into play, I would expect the closed loop gain to be down only 3dB (0.707) from unity at 1 MHz.

GBW/(noise gain) = bandwidth where the closed loop gain is down 3dB

(where the noise gain is equal to 1)

Therefore, if there was no slew rate limiting, the bandwidth would be 1MHz/1 = 1MHz. In other words, without slew-rate limiting, the unity closed loop gain would fall to 0.707 of its low frequency value by the time the frequency had increased to 1MHz.

Looking at your output-frequency plot it is apparent that the output starts to reduce in amplitude at a much lower frequency than can be attributed to the amplifier's open loop gain roll-off. In fact the output reduces from about 55kHz where the open loop gain is still quite large which, if slewrate limiting didn't come into play, would still be giving a closed loop gain close to unity.

Using the equation f = SR/(2 * pi * Vpk) = 500,000/(2 * pi * 1.414) = about 56kHz

And so we can see that the 741 is slew rate limiting leading to the output amplitude reducing from about 56kHz.

To illustrate this to your self you could, if possible, reduce the amplitude of the input signal and see if the reduction in output amplitude starts at a proportionately higher frequency bearing in mind that as the frequency increases the amplifier's bandwidth limitation will come more into play also contributing to output amplitude reduction.

Also, if possible, you could look at the amplifier's output signal in the time domain as a time varying signal and accertain if the signal's sinusoidal form starts to distort to a more triangular waveform as the frequency is increased above about 56kHz which would be a sign of slew rate limiting.

Comment: James, do you really expect to see slew rate effects in the frequency domain? No - certainly, this is not the case. But I agree - the presented results are surprising.  At first, I urgently recommend to use more test points (at least 10) in each decade. Moreover, because I am sure that there must be something wrong with the test set - the supply voltages must be shown. Perhaps there is something wrong with the DC operational point.

Comment: @LvW I would expect to see a slew rate limited waveform, that has changed from sinusoidal to triangular,  gradually reducing in amplitude  as frequency is further increased.

Comment: The 741 opamp design is 53 years old and it should be buried. It also produces a lot of hiss noise. Use a modern audio opamp instead.

Comment: James - we speak about analyses in the frequency domain. See the diagram: dB vs. frequency ! There is no other waveform than sinusoidal per definition. No slew rate effect possible.

Comment: @LvW Read my answer and comment again. Hopefully it will become clearer for you.

Comment: OK - following your advice, I comment again. Here is what you wrote: "And so we can see that the 741 is slew rate limiting leading to the output amplitude reducing from about 56kHz.".  Obviously, you have derived the frequency of 56 kHz from the diagram provided by the questioner. It shows the result of an ac-analysis (dB vs. f). I repeat: Such a small-signal  analysis is valid - per definition - for sinusoidal signals only. It is impossible that any distortions like slewing effects are included in the results. Please tell me - what is unclear in my comments? Am I wrong?

Comment: @LvW If you still don't believe me about this then get yourself a 741, set it up on breadboard as a unity gain buffer, apply 1V rms to its input and look at what the output does from about 56kHz. You will see that, as frequency increases further,  the waveform becomes triangular and the amplitude steadily reduces. You could do the same with a LM358 but, having a slew rate of 0.3V/us, the same effect will happen from about 30kHz. I really can't explain this to you any better than I have done already. Hopefully with the practical experiment you will soon understand, It's really quite simple.

Comment: James - Ok, I realize that you are not willing (or able) to react to my arguments. Do you know the difference between analyses in the time resp. frequency domain? Al your considerations are valid for the TIME domain only - but the shown diagram (subject of discussion) results from analyses in the FREQUENCY domain. This is a substantial difference. I have asked you to  "what was unclear in my comments" and "Am I wrong"? No response to these two simple questions. My advice: We should stop at this point. No fair exchange of arguments seems to be possible. It is a really a pitty.

Comment: @LvW As you say, you've read my answer and comments more than once. I hope you've carried out the practical experiment which I recommended because it perfectly illustrates the reality of the situation. I've done my absolute best to further your understanding. I'm afraid if you still don't understand this then you're just going to have to think harder and hopefully a little lit electric light bulb will appear above your head in a moment of true inspiration. Best of luck with this.

Comment: James - my last comment: I do not understand the meaning of your last contribution. It makes no sense to answer. I do not need any "practical experience" to realize that you are completely wrong. May I point to the fact that (a) the questioner has used a 1mV signal and (b)  a unity gain amplifier. Therefore, your calculation (resulting in 56 kHz) is simply wrong.  Slew rate limitation for unity gain and 1mV input and 1mV max output?

Comment: @LvW Read the original question again. The questioner has used a 1V rms (1.414V peak) input, not 1mV. I know one thing, the action of that circuit will be exactly the same irrespective of whether its operation is analysed in the frequency domain or the time domain.

Comment: James - you are right. This was an error on my side.  Indeed, the input voltage was 1Vrms (instead of 1mVrms). Apparently I need a new pair of glasses. You see, I have no problem admitting a mistake on my part. Therefore: Do you still believe that the influence of the slew rate can also be seen in a small-signal AC analysis? That is for sure: Your last sentence is not correct. There is a fundamental difference between analyses in the time resp. frequency domain. The math behind these two anylyses is completely different.

Comment: There is one thing that came just into my mind: The questioner did not tell us in detail how he has found the shown diagram. I was of the opinion (because of dB vs. frequency) that he has performed a small-signal analysis. The situation is different, of course, when he has performed a simulation (or measurement ?) in the time domain -   but has presented the results (by hand or with a special program) in a form typical for small signal analyses: dB versus frequency (log scale). Unfortunately, the OP gave no additional information.

Comment: @LvW Exactly, we have no idea how that plot was obtained. I think that may have been a "light bulb moment" for you! Your approach to the discussion is improving. Your starting to show a more compromising attitude to the discussion rather than your usual approach where you just seem to want to trade "arguments" in an apparent effort to beat your "opponent" into submission. I think it is a good approach to discuss in a manner that leads to mutual advancement and a resulting outcome that is beneficial to both parties in finding a better truth rather than just trying to win!

Comment: Quote: "....your usual approach where you just seem to want to trade "arguments" in an apparent effort to beat your "opponent" into submission." Thank you for your nice characterization of my personality ("usual approach"). Nevertheless, if something is wrong, I will call it wrong also in the future - like your statement: "..the action of that circuit will be exactly the same irrespective of whether its operation is analysed in the frequency domain or the time domain". End of discussion (from my side).

Comment: @LvW That wouldn't be the first time that you've inferred that it is your last comment of the discussion :-) I wonder if it will actually be your last comment? It is good to call something out as wrong when it is, I quite often do the same. The problem comes when you are classing something as incorrect when, in fact, it is absolutely accurate.